# using href to two links(php and a webpage)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

```
While($enreg=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
   $link_d.="<a href=\"$enreg[link]\" target=\"_blank\"><font color=\"red\">clic here to download</font></a></td>"
}
```

i want to use the href so it leads to download link, also to send the id to a php file so i can get how many times the files have been downloaded !
How can we use href to multiple links !

Comment: You are using too many double quotes !!

Comment: @woofmeow, How so?  All quotes are properly closed.

Comment: You have a mistake in your code. You need brackets when using an array in a string. href=\"{$enreg['link']}\".

Comment: @Brad they are closed yes i agree but its better to use single quotes `'` if you are to echo it. Makes it look better and is easier to read too

Comment: @woofmeow, I agree.  I was only saying that what is in the question is valid syntax, and your comment seemed to imply that the problem here had something to do with quotes.

Comment: Ok it might have sounded like that. I agree too :). Hope its more clear now to whoever reads it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would have some checks to see if it's a human downloading (Web crawlers may trigger it - we will put no-follow in the link which will help though). You could also use a database but that gets more complicated. My preferred way would be to use Google Analytics Events. But here is a simple PHP script that might fulfill your needs without the complexity of the other solutions.

First modify your links to have a tracker script and to urlencode

```
$link_d.= '<a style="color:red" href="tracker.php?url='.urlencode($enreg[link]).'" target="_blank">click here to download</a>';
```

}

Then create a script that will record downloads (tracker.php)

```
 <?php

// keep stats in a file - you can change the path to have it be below server root
// or just use a secret name - must be writeable by server
$statsfile = 'stats.txt';

// only do something if there is a url
if(isset($_GET['url'])) {

  //decode it
  $url = urldecode($_GET['url']);

  // Do whatever check you want here to see if it's a valud link - you can add a regex for a URL for example
  if(strpos($url, 'http') != -1) {

    // load current data into an array
    $lines = file($statsfile);

    // parse array into something useable by php
    $stats = array();
    foreach($lines as $line) {
      $bits = explode('|', $line);
      $stats[(string)$bits[0]] = (int)$bits[1];
    }

    // see if there is an entry already
    if(!isset($stats[$url])) {

      // no so let's add it with a count of 1
      $stats[$url] = 1;

    } else {

      // yes let's increment
      $stats[$url]++;

    }
    // get a blank string to write to file
    $data = null;

    // get our array into some human readabke format
    foreach($stats as $url => $count) {
      $data .= $url.'|'.$count."\n";
    }

    // and write to file
    file_put_contents($statsfile, $data);
  }

  // now redirect to file
  header('Location: ' . $url);

}
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, very thorough. I would just like to add that it would probably be best to not use the `<font>` tag in favor of letting the CSS do the styling. This script will work great either way, however.

Comment: @FireCrakcer37 good suggestion. Cleaned up the quotes while I was at it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  A link can only point to one resource.

Instead, what you should do is have your PHP script redirect to the file.  The link points at your PHP script with the counter, and then set a `Location:` header (which automatically sets a 302 status code for redirection) with the value being the URL you want to redirect to.

Also, you should really use `htmlspecialchars()` around any variable data you use in an HTML context, to ensure you are generating valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Anchor are meant to lead to one ressource.

What you want to do is tipically addressed by using an intermediate script that count the hit and redirect to the ressource.

eg.

```
<a href="redirect.php?id=42">Click here to download</a>
```

*redirect.php*

```
// Increment for example, a database :
// UPDATE downloads SET hits = (hits + 1) WHERE id=42

// Get the URI
// SELECT uri FROM downloads WHERE id=42

// Redirect to the URI
// (You may also need to set Content-type header for file downloads)
header( "Location: $uri" );
```

You may optimize this by passing the uri as a second parameter so that you won't need to fetch it at redirect time.

```
<a href="redirect.php?id=42&uri=/files/example.pdf">Click here to download</a>
```

Another way of collecting this kind of statistics is to use some javascript tools provided by your statistics provider, like Google Analytics or Piwik, adding a listener to the click event.

It is less invasive for your base code but won't let you easily reuse collected data in your site  (for example if you want to show a "top download" list).

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with download script for example `download.php` and route all your downloads through it. Update your counter in this page and use appropriate headers for download.

eg:

url may be `download.php?id=1&file=yourfile`

in `download.php`

```
//get id and file
//database operation to update your count
//headers for download
```